# Django: testing get query

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset

Okay, so I am sick of writing this...

```
res = Something.objects.filter(asdf=something)

if res:
  single = res[0]
else:
  single = None

if single:
  # do some stuff
```

I would much rather be able to do something like this:

```
single = Something.objects.filter(asdf=something)
if single:
  #do some stuff
```

I want to be able to grab a *single* object without testing the filtered results.

In other words, when i know there is either going to be 1 or 0 matching entries, I would like to jump right to that entry, otherwise just get a 'None'. The DoesNotExist error that goes along with .get does not always work so well when trying to compress these queries into a single line.

Is there any way to do what I have described?

Comment: "The DoesNotExist error that goes along with .get does not always work so well"?  "trying to compress these queries into a single line"?  The `get` method is the standard approach.  What's wrong with it?  What does "single line" mean when your `filter` example is not a single line, either?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Create a custom `Manager`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/managers/#id2) which encapsulates the bit you're sick of repeating as a method (with a better name than the one below) or just write a utility function which does the same without the hit to model definitions:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def get_or_none(self, **kwargs):
        try:
            return self.get(**kwargs)
        except self.model.DoesNotExist:
            return None

class MyModel(models.Model):
    objects = MyManager()
```

Usage:

```
MyModel.objects.get_or_none(asdf=something)
```

Answer (score 3):

The [django-annoying](http://bitbucket.org/offline/django-annoying/) project includes a `get_object_or_None` shortcut which does this, although it's trivial to write it yourself.